# Error Removing Ubuntu + Grub and reverting back to using Windows MBR

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-7, grubrescue

I Partitioned my hard disk back some time ago to install Ubuntu on it as I needed it for a college project. It became a bit of a pain when I finished my project when I had to select my OS each time I turned on my laptop and it often just automatically went in to Ubuntu.

While on windows in the disk management section I deleted the Ubuntu partition and then extended my windows one to fill the free space. When I turned on my laptop I was stuck at the grub rescue page we are all familiar with.

I've done much research and took note of various fixes.

As a result of me deleting the partition and extending into the free space, it is not an option to reinstall Ubuntu from a disk/USB and fix the booter this way. Also I do not have a copy of my windows installation disk so I cannot use this to rid myself of grub and revert back to using the Windows MBR!

So my question really is how do I get my laptop to use the Windows MBR again? Or does anyone know where I can obtain a free copy of a windows 7 installation to do a repair?

Kind regards, Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a free 90 day trial version of Windows from [Microsoft TechNet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise). Now create a bootable DVD / USB media and boot from it, on Install now screen select Repair your computer.
Choose Command prompt and execute the following commands to install the Windows loader :

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: I'm currently on Windows 7, will I be able to repair it using a trial version of Windows 8 or 10?

Answer (score 0):

A second solution if you don't have a second pc to write a windows and you only have a live ubuntu cd and for some reason you cant write a windows 7 dvd or usb (this normally works http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) then do this:

- Shrink windows partition using from ubuntu live as described here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions (if the installer's partition manager doesn't work, then use the try option and install `gparted`).
- Install Ubuntu
- Boot to windows and restore mbr using this tool https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ as explained here https://superuser.com/questions/114435/repair-windows-bootmanager-from-within-windows
- Then delete Ubuntu's partition and extend your windows' partition as before